# Tikz: empty nodes with different style (coordinate)

Tags: tikz-pgf

In tikz if I enable `nodes in empty cells=true`, a node is added en each empty cell of the matrix. I'd like to turn each empty node with `shape=coordinate` (and **not** as a node with `inner sep=0pt`, as these nodes are still a few pixels wide), as otherwise the empty nodes take some space.

Is it possible to, somehow, to use a different style that applies only to empty nodes?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

With inner sep=0pt (see the gaps, I don't want to use start anchor=center because not all nodes want to be linked from the center):\\
\noindent\begin{tikzcd}[
  nodes in empty cells=true,
  /tikz/every node/.style={
    nodes={draw,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},
  },
  ]
  \rar[-] & \rar[-] & Hey
\end{tikzcd}

With shape coordinate (no more gaps, but ALL nodes are turned into coordinate… and disappear  I could force another shape using shape=rectangle, but I don't want to manually change all nodes):\\
\noindent\begin{tikzcd}[
  nodes in empty cells=true,
  /tikz/every node/.style={
    nodes={draw,shape=coordinate},
  },
  ]
  \rar[-] & \rar[-] & Hey\\
\end{tikzcd}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `matrix` library (which is used by TikZ-CD via `matrix of nodes` and `matrix of math nodes` simply uses [`execute at empty cell`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices#tikz/execute:at:begin:cell) that checks whether `nodes in empty cells` is set to true and if it is it places an empty node.

We can simply overwrite this (ignoring the `nodes in empty cells` toggle) by specifying

```
execute at empty cell={
  \coordinate[
    yshift=axis_height,
    name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn
  ]
}
```

The `axis_height` is necessary because the other nodes in the same row are placed at their baseline and the vertical center of those nodes are at *y* = `axis_height` which is a PGFMath function/value that is used by TikZ-CD's own `asymmetrical rectangle` shape for its vertical center. (This is done so that arrows between cells in the same row are always horizontal and roughly at natural height, like the minus sign.)

This is also basically what happens when you use `|[*]|` as in the first example since no cell there is actually empty.

Those with `\arrow` et al in them will be a node.

I'll hijack an internal TikZ hook to set the shape of the node to `coordinate` unless it already was because then we don't need to do another `axis_height` shift.

This will prevent you from having a real empty node, i.e. one with no text or explicit `text width = 0pt` will make a coordinate.
For this, I'll have a toggle so that this check will only happen when it is set to true (which is the default for `empty cells as coordinate despite arrow`).

I am overwriting the macro that procceses the `|…|` syntax so that it will not be checked for “emptiness” (unless you switch `empty node check` again).

### Code

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\makeatletter
% a coordinate in an empty cell needs some special care about axis_height
\def\tikzcd@emptycell@coordinate{%
  \coordinate[yshift=axis_height,name=\tikzmatrixname
    -\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn];}
% overwriting original, a explicit || node shouldn't become a coordinate
\def\tikz@lib@matrix@with@options|#1|{\tikz@lib@matrix@plainfalse\node
  [empty node check=false,name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow
    -\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn]#1\bgroup\tikz@lib@matrix@startup}%

\newif\iftikz@emptynodecheck
\tikzcdset{
  /tikz/empty node check/.is if=tikz@emptynodecheck,
  empty cells as coordinates despite arrow/.style={
    /tikz/empty node check,
    /tikz/every matrix/.append style={
      /tikz/execute at empty cell=\tikzcd@emptycell@coordinate,
      /tikz/every node/.append code={%
        \tikz@addoption{%
          \iftikz@emptynodecheck
            \ifdim\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox=0pt %
              \pgfutil@ifx\tikz@shape\tikz@coordinate@text{}{%
                \def\tikz@shape{coordinate}%
                \pgftransformyshift{axis_height}}%
            \fi\fi}}}}}
\makeatother

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mycircle}{}{|[circle, draw, inner sep=3pt]|}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}% just for this
\begin{document}
Each ``empty'' cell gets \texttt{|[*]|}
to force a coordinate at the right height.\par
\begin{tikzcd}[
  cells={nodes=draw},
  /tikz/*/.style={shape=coordinate, yshift=axis_height}]
  |[*]| \rar[-] & |[*]| \rar[-] & Hey
\end{tikzcd}

With \texttt{empty cells as coordinate despite arrow}
real empty cells as well as ``empty'', i.\,e. cells
with \verb|\ar|, \verb|\arrow|, \verb|\rar|, \dots
gets detected.\par
\begin{tikzcd}[
  empty cells as coordinates despite arrow,
  cells={nodes=draw}, arrows=-]
  \rar &  & Hey \lar & \mycircle \lar
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: The `matrix of (math) nodes` styles install a few checks at the start of the cell but they include some “evil trickery” that seem to make it impossible to check for anything else at the start of a cell (like an `\arrow`).

Comment: Thank you so much! But I still have a small issue with this code: if I add in your second diagram a node like `|[circle, draw, inner sep=3pt]|` (and I use this **a lot**, using some macros to create special nodes) it is replaced with a coordinate and therefore no circle is drawn. I guess that it's because of `\pgfnodeparttextbox` that does not check if a style is non-empty… by any chance, do you know if it's possible to fix this case?

Comment: @tobiasBora Yeah, that was what I was afraid of and mentioned in my last paragraph. Every “empty” node will be caught that way. As I said, we will add another toggle that disables that check. And we could also make it so that any cell with `|` options doesn't do that to begin with. Will need to wait though because I'm not on a PC for the next few hours.

Comment: I would like to just check for `\arrow` et al at the start of a cell but all I'm getting from ifnextchar is `\relax` which isn't bad but it would also get triggered when a cell starts with, say, `\textbf`.

Comment: Ahah no problem, take your time, and thanks a lot for your help. And would it be catched if I define `\NewExpandableCommand{\mycommand}{m}{|[circle, draw, inner sep=3pt]|}` and use it to create a new cell? That's the case that I really don't want to miss ^^

Comment: @tobiasBora The expandable macro works, but you could always just define the whole `\node` command there anyway (don't forget `name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn`).